# Can't access webpage fields values after opening in chrome via powershell

Tags: powershell

being as a new boy in powershell, learning it.
I am able to open my URL in chrome but unable to access any of the fields of my URL.
below is my code working fine to  open URL in chrome but able to retrieve any field value.

```
$TargetURL = "https://servicenow.contasa.com/textsearch.do?login_redirect.do?sysparm_no_redirect=false&sysparm_search=INC09329323"

$S = [system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome",$TargetURL)
$S
```

Please guide how fields can be accessed using powershell

Comment: Why not using [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)?

Comment: @iRon: I used ```invoke-webrequest``` as below
```$Target = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://servicenow.contasa.com/textsearch.do?login_redirect.do?sysparm_no_redirect=false&sysparm_search=INC09329323"
$Target```
but its opening only "https://servicenow.contasa.com" default URL but not the URL assigned in $target value.

Comment: Hey all! In advance happy new year to all.
could anyone please help on my query on how to access fields value data and capture in variable?

Comment: It is difficult to help you as we do not have access to the concerned page. Besides you using `[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start` is usually not the way to scrape webpages **in PowerShell**. As suggested, you probably want to do (*multiple*) `invoke-webrequest`s to get to the page you want. The way you try is is more something for RPA application, theregore you might consider to use [UiPath](https://www.uipath.com/) instead.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get more responses to your question.